# Why does IP = PSPACE

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity, lower-bounds, upper-bound, interactive-proof-systems

Can anyone give an intuitive explanation to why IP = PSPACE, or at least one direction of it?

I looked at many research papers but its very hard to understand the formalism unless you have a solid background in Turing machines and complexity theory. I'm an undergraduate.

Answer (score 1):

I found it most easy to understand according to reference [here](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/gs019/papers/ip.pdf) for undergrad level:

> It's easy to show that IP $\subseteq$ PSPACE . Suppose L ∈ IP . Then we have some verifier V
> for L. The PSPACE algorithm we use to decide L is to compute
> z = max Pr[V ↔ P accepts w] .
> By the definition of IP , if z ≥ 2/3 , then we know that w ∈ L. If z ≤ 1/3 , then we know that w !∈ L. Note that if V is a verifier for L, 1/3 < z < 2/3 will never occur.

> Now we need to show that it's possible to compute z in PSPACE. Suppose V runs in p(n) steps, where n = |w|. Then any given response by P is no longer than p(n). Also, V chooses at most p(n) random numbers. We may recursively simulate V while branching for each random number, and each possible response by P. Therefore, the recursion depth is *polynomial*, so we can perform such a recursion in PSPACE. We keep a count of the accepting branches produced by P's optimal responses, as well as the total number of branches. These numbers will be *exponential* in n, but the length of the numerical representation is *polynomial* in n. The ratio computed by this PSPACE algorithm is z, therefore IP $\subseteq$ PSPACE.

Another related intuition is imagine a limit case where a subset of IP is the deterministic Interactive Proof class, which is similar to IP but has a deterministic verifier. This class is equal to NP and thus we can kind of intuited this subset of IP = NP $\subseteq$ PSPACE. The other direction, however, is much harder from the same reference:

> Recall that TQBF, the language of true quantified boolean formulas, is PSPACE-complete. Therefore, PSPACE ⇔ TQBF ∈ IP. The goal of this paper will be to show TQBF ∈ IP, hence IP = PSPACE...

I'm no expert here, hope this will be somewhat helpful.